# How do I stop motion_add?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

So, basically when I fire I want some recoil and `motion_add` does seem perfect but it wont stop so are there any good alternatives to just have a sudden push or a way to stop the `motion_add` from happening multiple times. Thanks in advance!

```
if oShotgun.hasFired
{
    motion_add(-oShotgun.image_angle, oShotgun.backBlast)
    hasFired = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify where `oShotgun.hasFired` is set to true, and in which Event that's located? I think the cause is that `oShotgun.hasFired` is set to true multiple times.

Comment: Sorry for not responding so long. I actually use motion_set in start function for bullets so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but you should set the built-in variable "speed" to 0.